# How to create a rotated texture from another already rotated in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, xcode6, texture-atlas

I’m creating a sprite from a `SKTexture`, that in turn was created from another texture loaded from an atlas, like this:

```
SKTexture *textureFromAtlas = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@“MyImage.png”];
CGRect myRect = textureFromAtlas.textureRect;
myRect.size.with *= 0.5;
myRect.size.height *= 0.5;
SKTexture *newTexture = [SKTexture textureWithRect:myRect inTexture:textureFromAtlas];
SKSpriteNode * MySprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:newTexture];
```

`textureFromAtlas` happened to be rotated, since inside the folder ***Images.atlasc*** in the application bundle, ***Images.1.png*** shows ***MyImage.png*** rotated, and ***Images.plist*** has the key ***textureRotated*** set to YES for that sub-image

How can I create `MySprite` so that it has the right rotation?

[image]

**(A)** is what one would expect, since SpriteKit does the auto rotation thing;
**(B)** is the actual result, i.e. what one gets with the code from above

***Edit:***

I had to add some code to get the size of ***MyImage.png***, but the rotated one contained in the atlas, to see whether it is rotated, and then calculate a new rotated `myRect` to use for `mySrpite`

```
CGRect textureRect = textureFromAtlas.textureRect;
CGSize atlasSize = [[SKTexture textureWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
                                     inTexture:textureFromAtlas] size];
CGSize sizeInAtlas = CGSizeMake(textureRect.size.width * atlasSize.width,
                                textureRect.size.height * atlasSize.height);
myRect = CGRectMake(myRect.origin.x,
                    myRect.origin.y+myRect.size.height-sizeInAtlas.height/atlasSize.height);
SKTexture *rotatedTexture = [SKTexture textureWithRect:myRect
                                             inTexture:textureFromAtlas];
mySprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteWithTexture: rotatedTexture];
mySprite.zRotation = M_PI_2;
```

This effectively "moves" the rect to the upper-left corner of the rotated image in ***Image.1.png***, so that `mySprite` would be the one in **(A)**, however this only works if the MyImage.png is fully opaque or has no transparent borders, because SpriteKit make some optimisations with those images with transparency, and the textureRect is smaller than the actual frame in the atlas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there appears to be a bug with textureWithRect:inTexture when using a texture that comes from an SKTextureAtlas. This kind of make sense because what you are trying to do is create a sprite map from a sprite map and I can see this causing some performance issues.

To get your desired resutls I see it working two different ways.

First option move MyImage out side of an atlas folder (or use asset catelog) and use the textureWithRect:inTexture. This is ideal if the image is already created as a sprite sheet and you don't want to chop it up. This isn't a bad solution but you will likely get better results with the second option.

```
SKTexture *textureFromAtlas = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@“MyImage.png”];
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0,.5,.5,.5);
SKTexture *newTexture = [SKTexture textureWithRect:myRect inTexture:textureFromAtlas];
SKSpriteNode * MySprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:newTexture];
```

Second option chop up your image and then add those images to images.atlas This is more ideal if you want to get other textures that may be rendered at the same time on one sprite sheet (atlas). SpriteKit will take care of the putting them together as one image at run time.

[image]

Red/Green would be the chopped up image that then gets combined and pink/green is just one image like you had before.

You would then would be able to easily use code like...

```
SKTexture *textureFromAtlas = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"MyImage1.png"];
SKSpriteNode *mySprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:textureFromAtlas];
```

Both options do not require worrying about rotation. Even if the .atlas rotates it when you get the image out it won't be rotated.

Comment: I've put together a [test project](https://anonfiles.com/file/5c3ee634b899c4fde1c390807894860f) with the code you suggested, and it doesn't work, maybe I'm missing something. I would expect `mySprite` to be only 25% of the normal image (i.e. 0 in line 14 of GameScene.m)

Comment: When you said atlasc I thought the c was a typo. Are you using texturepacker?

Comment: @rraallvv I updated my answer. I verified that the plist is the same as to what Apple creates on the fly for rotated images. I also verified that it does work for images outside of an atlas. I updated my answer with these new finding.

Comment: hmm... your way seems easier, but I can't get it to work, please take a look at this [other test project](https://anonfiles.com/file/814f0cd0b4e9306a49e146d6e1934557), it's basically the same but with the atlas using separate files, I thing this is definitely a bug

Comment: @rraallvv I updated my answer to better show the two ways to approach your problem. I also updated you example in the format I am explaining with the two different options. https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvkhhx5rf28x5i9/test3.zip?dl=0"

Comment: I’ll probably use the first option you suggested, putting the image outside the atlas, since myRect can change at runtime, I can’t chop MyImage.png in smaller pieces. I think I’m going to accept your answer since there isn’t much that can be done, [the documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKTexture/textureWithRect:inTexture:) that I need to calculate the coordinates myself, that is why I’m trying to get metrics from the atlas, but that doesn’t work if that method ignores the rect I’m passing.